# How to get DN for a DirectorySearcher's SearchResult in .NET?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

How can we reliably get the `DN` of a `SearchResult`?

We've been using `SearchResult.Properties["dn"]` but recently encountered an installation where this is not supported.  This customer has other applications that boil down to calling Win32's `ldap_get_dn` method, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for `SearchResult` in .NET.

The solution needs to work across LDAP servers, not ActiveDirectory-specific.

Comment: what operating system is the client using..? can you access AD or LDAP using your standard DirectorySearcher

Comment: @DJ KRAZE, yes, we can bind to the LDAP with a known DN and use `DirectorySearcher` to find other entries, but once we find the entry we need to get that entry's `DN` and the directory doesn't have an actual `DN` attribute defined as we've seen in every other LDAP installation (hundreds of installations, many different operating systems and LDAP servers).

Comment: do you know what their Directory tree looks like.. It sounds like the client is not using AD the way that it was intended.. I had a similar issue with a client about 10 months ago.. I would actually have to see an example of what you have in order to know I have some work around code that worked for me..

Comment: @DJ KRAZE, the client is not using Active Directory.  I don't know right now what they are using (I've asked, am awaiting that answer), but really it doesn't matter since the solution really needs to work across all clients using many different LDAP servers.

Comment: I know that from past experience that you can use the same style of search criteria for LDAP.. what ever the case sounds like you may need to ask a few more questions on their end..let us know what you find and how we can be of assistance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't clear at first but we later found out the `SearchResult.Path` property contains the DN and can be parsed for it.  This worked consistently with all servers we've encountered so far.

```
SearchResult result;
...
string userDn = result.Path;

// typical Path is
// LDAP://my.ldap.server.com:39/CN=a,CN=b,OU=c
// we want to grab the part after the third '/'
int i = userDn.IndexOf('/', 7);
if (i >= 0 && userDn.Length > i + 1)
{
    userDn = userDn.Substring(i + 1);
}
```

**SearchResult.Path Property**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.path.aspx

Comment: But the path contains the protocol as well which isn't technically part of the DN.

Comment: @ach, thanks, I overlooked the part in the code I wrote where I parse the DN out of the Path.  I updated the answer.

Comment: This may work for most setups. But the server and port won't always be present in the path. I think this is tricky, without knowing all of the rules for the LDAP Uri. I am no expert on LDAP, so I think your best bet is to do something like:
userDN = new Uri(result.Path).Segments.Last();

Comment: @ach, good point.  We've been using the above now in over 200 installations with lots of random LDAP servers and haven't had any issues with it.  Of course, we only ever ran into one install that had an issue with `SearchResult.Properties["dn"]`.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon  `new Uri(result.Path).Segments.Last();` only works if a server is specified.  If no server is specified a `System.UriFormatException` is thrown.  "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed"  As you point out a server is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The `base object`, which is always a distinguished name, is made available via the LDAP search result entry (but not a search result reference). The distinguished name is not an attribute, however.